# Can you control the virtual DOM with controlled component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

I have a quick react question, do you have the flexibility to control the virtual DOM with controlled component in React

Comment: VirtualDOM is maintained by react framework. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks a lot, I was asked that question and I said the same thing in an interview. I was just curious to know if I was right cause the interviewer didnt say anything when I said thats the whole point of React, it handles that